# How to disable a submit button until all the YUP fields are validated and enabled it without clicking outside the input field?

Tags: reactjs, yup

photo of the bug

[image: 1]

I have this react component:

```
import { FC, FormEventHandler } from 'react';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import { useResetPasswordMutation } from 'redux/api/authenticationApi';

import InputField from 'components/ui/atoms/InputField';
import NewPasswordField from 'components/ui/atoms/NewPasswordField';
import { KeysIcon } from 'components/ui/atoms/Icon';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface UpdatePasswordFormProps {
  token: string;
  onSent: () => void;
}

const schema = yup
  .object({
    password: yup
      .string()
      .label('Password')
      .required()
      .min(8)
      .test('isValidPass', ' is not valid', (value: any, context) => {
        const hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(value);
        const hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test(value);
        const hasNumber = /[0-9]/.test(value);
        const hasSymbole = /[!@#%&]/.test(value);
        let validConditions = 0;
        const numberOfMustBeValidConditions = 3;
        const conditions = [hasLowerCase, hasUpperCase, hasNumber, hasSymbole];
        conditions.forEach((condition) =>
          condition ? validConditions++ : null
        );
        if (validConditions >= numberOfMustBeValidConditions) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }),
    password_confirmation: yup
      .string()
      .label('Password confirmation')
      .required()
      .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
  })
  .required();

interface Inputs extends yup.InferType<typeof schema> {
  token: string;
  base: null;
}

const UpdatePasswordForm: FC<UpdatePasswordFormProps> = ({ token, onSent }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setError, formState } = useForm<Inputs>({
    mode: 'onTouched',
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const [resetPassword] = useResetPasswordMutation();
  register('base', { disabled: true });

  const onSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
    try {
      await handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        await resetPassword({ ...data, token }).unwrap();
        onSent();
      })(event);
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.data && 'errors' in error.data) {
        const errors = {} as { [key: string]: string[] };
        error.data.errors.forEach(
          ({
            title,
            details,
            source
          }: {
            title: string;
            details: string[];
            source?: { pointer: string };
          }) => {
            const pointer =
              source?.pointer &&
              Object.keys(schema.fields).includes(source.pointer)
                ? source.pointer
                : 'base';
            errors[pointer] = errors[pointer] ?? [];
            if (details && details.length > 0) {
              errors[pointer].push(...details);
            } else {
              errors[pointer].push(title);
            }
          }
        );
        Object.entries(errors).forEach(([pointer, errors]) => {
          if (['password', 'password_confirmation', 'base'].includes(pointer)) {
            setError(
              pointer as any,
              { type: 'custom', message: errors.join('. ') },
              { shouldFocus: true }
            );
          }
        });
      } else {
        const errorMessage =
          typeof error.data == 'string' ? error.data : 'Something went wrong.';
        setError(
          'base',
          { type: 'custom', message: errorMessage },
          { shouldFocus: true }
        );
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex w-82 flex-col text-inpay-black-500">
      <KeysIcon
        width="40"
        height="40"
        className="mb-4 flex h-10 w-10 self-center stroke-inpay-black-500 stroke-1.5"
      />
      <h1 className="mb-5 text-center text-[2rem] font-medium tracking-[0.01rem]">
        Create new password
      </h1>
      <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <NewPasswordField
          {...register('password')}
          label="Enter new password"
          errorMessage={formState.errors.password?.message}
        />
        <InputField
          {...register('password_confirmation')}
          type="password"
          label="Repeat password"
          className="mt-12"
          errorMessage={formState.errors.password_confirmation?.message}
        />
        <button
          className="mt-10 h-12 rounded-lg bg-inpay-green-700 p-2 text-base font-medium text-white disabled:bg-inpay-gray-700"
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
          disabled={
            formState.isSubmitSuccessful ||
            !formState.isValid ||
            Object.keys(Error).length > 0
          }
        >
          Create new password
        </button>
        {formState.errors.base && (
          <div
            role="alert"
            className="mt-2 rounded-lg bg-rose-100 p-3 text-sm text-rose-600"
          >
            {formState.errors.base.message}
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
      <div className="mt-24 text-center">
        <Link to="/login" className="font-medium text-inpay-blue-600 underline">
          Back to log in
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdatePasswordForm;
```

I am trying to disable the submit button until all the input fields are satisfied, but the bug is that if I add a valid password in both fields the button is still deactivated, it becomes active only if I click outside the input fields. Is there a way to activate the button as soon as I enter the last character of the input field and only if it matches all the criteria? if I click outside even if the password does not have all the mandatory fields it makes the button active.

I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `useForm` hook, you can change `mode` to `'onChange'` and add `reValidateMode: 'onChange'`, to cause validation to occur onChange rather than onBlur.

**mode**

> 'onChange': Validation will trigger on the change event with each input, and lead to multiple re-renders. Warning: this often comes with a significant impact on performance.

**reValidateMode**

> This option allows you to configure validation strategy when inputs with errors get re-validated after a user submits the form (onSubmit event). By default, validation is triggered during the input change event.

See: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform#useFormRef

Comment: thanks a lot gunwin, if I understand correctly I should just add mode: 'onSubmit',
  reValidateMode: 'onChange' ? if i add mode: onChange it throws me errors